# VBA DAO.Recordset is null or not set when trying to close it - But I check if its null beforehand

Tags: vba, ms-access, transactions, dao

In an access application's VBA code there is a function to convert some database fields over to another format. This happens for 2 tables, in code you can tell them appart by the 2 loops, for BOM and ROUTING. This code had poor performance because sometimes 200000+ records passed through it. In order to speed it up I added transactions to it- its 3x as fast now. However, when trying to close the ROUTING recordset, I get an error saying "object invalid or no longer set". Therefor I added 2 checks to it, a not nothing and not null before I attempt to close it. when stepping through with the debugger it passes both checks and then attempts to close the recordset, then goes to ErrorHandler which gives the message. What makes this error extra weird is that it has no problems closing the BOM recordset for the first loop. 
Code:

```
Public Sub SomeSub()
    ' set up variables
    Dim BOM As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ROUTING As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Workspace As DAO.Workspace
    Set Workspace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

    ' set up errorhandler
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' run some process on BOM
    Set BOM = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("some query;", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges, dbOptimistic)
    Workspace.BeginTrans
    If Not (BOM.BOF And BOM.EOF) Then
        BOM.MoveFirst
        Do While (Not BOM.EOF) And (Not BOM.BOF)
            ' Do some stuff with BOM here
            BOM.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    Workspace.CommitTrans
    BOM.Close
    Set BOM = Nothing



    Set ROUTING = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("some query;", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges, dbOptimistic)
    Workspace.BeginTrans
    If Not (ROUTING.BOF And ROUTING.EOF) Then
        ROUTING.MoveFirst

        Do While (Not ROUTING.EOF)
            ' Do some stuff with ROUTING here
            ROUTING.MoveNext

        Loop
    End If

    Workspace.CommitTrans
    Workspace.Close

    If Not ROUTING Is Nothing Then
        If Not ROUTING Is Null Then
            ROUTING.Close
        End If
    End If

    GoTo SuccesHandler
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Ran into error. Info: " & Err.number & ": " & Err.DESCRIPTION & vbNewLine
    Resume SuccesHandler
SuccesHandler:
End Sub
```

Questions: 
- Why does this error happen?
- What is the proper way of null/nothing checking? (obviously the way Im doing it doesn't work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `Recordset` before closing the `Workspace`.

```
Workspace.CommitTrans

If Not ROUTING Is Nothing Then
    ROUTING.Close
    Set ROUTING= Nothing
End If

Workspace.Close
Set Workspace = Nothing
```

Comment: This worked. Code runs fine now, thanks! I would like to know why though. Does the workspace have to do with all the DAO records you instantiate or update within a transaction? Does closing the workspace close all the recordsets updated with said workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust that block to match the one that works - and move the Workspace handling out of the block:

```
Set ROUTING = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("some query;", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges, dbOptimistic)
Workspace.BeginTrans
If Not (ROUTING.BOF And ROUTING.EOF) Then
    ROUTING.MoveFirst
    Do While (Not ROUTING.EOF)
        ' Do some stuff with ROUTING here
        ROUTING.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
Workspace.CommitTrans
ROUTING.Close
Set ROUTING = Nothing

Set Workspace = Nothing
```

Comment: This worked. Code runs fine now, thanks! I would like to know why though. Does the workspace have to do with all the DAO records you instantiate or update within a transaction? Does closing the workspace close all the recordsets updated with said workspace?

Comment: You should not close the current workspace, just like you never close CurrentDb. Also, a common rule is to always set objects to Nothing in reverse order of which they have been opened. It is seldom an issue in Access, but in Excel it may cause serious trouble.

Comment: So I should use a globally defined workspace, defined the same way as CurrentDB?

Comment: Yes, do that. You may also replace `CurrentDb` with a _DAO.Database_ object you set to `WorkSpace(0)`.